# How can I do repeated addition to a String in a loop?

Tags: java, string, append

```
for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(26);
    System.out.print(alphabet[randomNumber]);
}
```

I am making a sort of memory game-like program to create a String of random letters and then have it disappear off the screen so the user has to remember it and type it in correctly. Level 1 has 1 letter, level 2 has 2 letters, and so on.

The above code is a for loop I have that uses a String array I made containing each letter of the alphabet called `"alphabet[]"` and a randomly generated number. My problem is that I do not know how to add the letters each time on to a String so that I can check it against what the user inputs.

For example, if on level 3 the output is `"abc,"` how do I get that into a single String, and not just three separate Strings? In other words, I want to do the same thing commonly done to integers like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++;) {
    int test += 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! Your help solved the problem!!!

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you are looking for is "String concatenation".
You can concat 2 string with "+" sign as in integer. But you need to define it as String first.

```
String word = "";
for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
{
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(26);
    word += alphabet[randomNumber];
}
System.out.println(word);
```

Given that your `alphabet` is array of String.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in JAVA:

```
String pqr = "";
int a = 0;
pqr = pqr + a;
```

String concatenation is that easy;-)

And here is a simpler way i can think of where you dont need the alphabet array. You just need to know Ascii value of 'A' and add your random number as offset and typecast to char

```
String question_string = "";
for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(26);
    question_string = question_string + (char)(randomNumber+65);
}   
System.out.println(question_string);
```

here 65 is ascii of A

Answer (score 0):

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String string = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        string += scanner.next();
    }
    System.out.println("string = " + string);
```

this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to the result you want.

Something like:

```
String test = "";

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    test += i;
}

System.out.println(test); // "01234"
```

...would work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my level is 10 and my alphabet contain only a-j.

You might want to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(10);
        word = word + alphabet[randomNumber];                
    }
    System.out.println(word);
    word = "";      //clear word
}
```

Output:

```
i
bj
eab
djbj
ccdjf
aicbfc
iiiedie
afcfjdgi
abicbgiig
figabajcfb
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
String input = "";
for(int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(26);
    input = input + randomNumber ;
}
System.out.print("Input String is: " + input);
String userInput; //Get the output string from user.
if(input.equals(userInput))
  System.out.println("You are right");
else
  System.out.println("Sorry! You are wrong");
```

For reading a string from user input you can try this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner ( System.in );
String userInput= scanner .nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use StringBuilder...

```
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(26);
    word.append(alphabet[randomNumber]);          
}
```